# Selectively deleting elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of strings:

```
  lis = {{"w", "u"}, {"q", "r"}, {"z"}, {"d", "e"}, {"f"}, {"g", "h"}, {"o"}}
```

I would like to delete all single-element members of this list to give:

```
  res = {{"w","u"}, {"q","r"}, {"d","e"}, {"g","h"}}

  SequenceCases[lis, {{a_, b_}, {_}, {c_, d_}} :> {{a, b}, {c, d}}, Overlaps -> True]
```

fails.  Apologies for this simple question!

Comment: `res = DeleteCases[lis, _List?(Length[#] < 2 &)]`

Comment: `DeleteCases[lis, {_}]`

Comment: `Cases[lis,{x_,y_}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding patterns:

```
Select[lis, Length[#] > 1 &]
{{w,u},{q,r},{d,e},{g,h}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this using `ReplaceAll`:

```
ReplaceAll[lis, x : {_} :> Nothing]

{{"w", "u"}, {"q", "r"}, {"d", "e"}, {"g", "h"}}
```

Also, using `Cases`:

```
Cases[lis, x : {__} /; Length[x] > 1]

{{"w", "u"}, {"q", "r"}, {"d", "e"}, {"g", "h"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your try with `SequenceCases` failed

```
Join @@ SequenceCases[lis, {{_, _} ..}]
```

{{"w", "u"}, {"q", "r"}, {"d", "e"}, {"g", "h"}}

Or

```
SequenceReplace[{{_} ..} :> Nothing] @ lis
```

{{"w", "u"}, {"q", "r"}, {"d", "e"}, {"g", "h"}}

In addition to the answers already given `better candidates` would include

```
Cases[{_, _}] @ lis
```

{{"w", "u"}, {"q", "r"}, {"d", "e"}, {"g", "h"}}

and

```
 Pick[lis, Length /@ lis, 2]
```

{{"w", "u"}, {"q", "r"}, {"d", "e"}, {"g", "h"}}